# Improve performance of in() out() and both()

Tags: graph, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Consider we have Vertex User, Post and Edge FriendsWith, HasPost. FriendsWith can be in both directions out and in (usually it is either out or in between 2 users). User is owner of Post.

We got 600000 users and 75 million of Posts

I use to get user friends following query:

`SELECT both('FriendsWith') FROM #12:1`

and to get friend posts

`SELECT both('FriendsWith').out('HasPost') FROM #12:1 LIMIT 50`

but if a user got many friends (~1000) the performance is not the best (~ 400 ms for getting friends and 1-5 sec on getting posts)

Is there any way to improve this queries ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

`select from (select expand(both('FriendsWith').out('HasPost')) from #12:1) LIMIT 50`

50 item(s) found. Query executed in 7.08 sec(s).

Comment: About the posts, in the case of 5 seconds, how many records are fetched? Are you interested only on the first 50? Try: `SELECT FROM ( SELECT expand( both('FriendsWith').out('HasPost') ) FROM #12:1 ) LIMIT 50`

Comment: Yes in the first 50. I will add performance results later. Your proposal didn't really change results.

Comment: @Lvca can I use fetchingPlan to speed up getting friend posts?